# Creating charts and including them in email, a PHP lib that can render to image?

Tags: php, codeigniter, charts, highcharts

I'm a fan of [highcharts.js](http://www.highcharts.com) for presenting charts on my webpages but a need to render unique bar graphs for ~300 users and send via email several times a year ('member update' sort of thing) has me looking for another library that can render to image.

As I understand it, none of the 'nice' looking chart libraries that make extensive use of CSS/jQuery etc will work in the treacherous ground that is HTML email.

Can anyone reccomend a straight-forward library based in PHP (I'm using code igniter) that lets one save the chart as an image and customise the display of the chart?

Comment: You might want to look into doing something with a web browser and some user scripts like greasemonkey.  The browser could be programmed to visit the URLs of the charts you need, and save them as image files (like an automated screen capture).  As opposed to changing your entire existing charting infrastructure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an open-source charting library called PChart that will accomplish exactly what you need. [PChart](http://www.pchart.net/) can render the image of the chart directly to the browser, or, it can save it to a file. See [Script Output](http://wiki.pchart.net/doc.faq.script.output.html) in the docs. The idea would be to save it to the server, and use it as the `src` attribute of an `<img>` tag in the email.

pChart requires the GD and FreeType PHP extensions to be installed on your web server. Call `phpinfo()` from any script and ctrl+f for 'Freetype' and 'GD' to check if they are enabled. If not, first enable them.

As far as integration with CodeIgniter, you should be able to cherry-pick the classes you need out of the `class` directory and toss them into the `application/libraries` directory.

From there, you'll be able to execute:

```
$this->load->library('pDraw');
$this->pDraw->someMethod();
```

And so on with the other relevant classes.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just create a webpage that houses the data in a pretty graph and send a URL in the email with a Unique ID to allow them to view the graph/data?